# You attempted to use a fire base module that's not installed on your android project by calling firebase.analytics()

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-analytics, react-native-firebase

I have installed firebase into my react native app, I will need to firebase analytics module.

**app/build.gradle:**

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1"
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashScreenTheme);  // here
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
    mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
}
```

**react native**

```
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
firebase.analytics().logEvent("your_custom_event", {"custom_parm": "cp_value"});
```

but I get this error on logcat console on android studio:

> E/ReactNativeJS: Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.analytics().
>
> Ensure you have:
>
> 1) Installed the required Firebase Android SDK dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics' in your 'android/app/build.gradle' file.
>
> 2) Imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.analytics.RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.
>
> 3) Added the 'new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.
>
> See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions.

and in react native console I see:

> D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**:
I was using the wrong version:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.4.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=> mainAppliction.java

add these line

import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage; // <-- Add this line

and add package

packages.add(new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage());


  implementation project(':clevertap-react-native')
  implementation 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.6.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
  // This should be here already
  implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

  // Firebase dependencies
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
```